# counting checkboxes with jquery and IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, checkbox

```
<div class="cbox rounded-corners">
<div>....<div>  
<div id="sendclientid">Send to Client:<span><input type="checkbox" name="sendtoclient[]" class='sendtoclient' value="1" ></span></div>
<div>...</div>
</div>
 <div class="cbox rounded-corners">
<div>....<div>  
<div id="sendclientid">Send to Client:<span><input type="checkbox" name="sendtoclient[]" class='sendtoclient' value="2" ></span></div>
<div>...</div>
</div>
 <div class="cbox rounded-corners">
<div>....<div>  
<div id="sendclientid">Send to Client:<span><input type="checkbox" name="sendtoclient[]" class='sendtoclient' value="3" ></span></div>
<div>...</div>
</div>
 <div class="cbox rounded-corners">
<div>....<div>  
<div id="sendclientid">Send to Client:<span><input type="checkbox" name="sendtoclient[]" class='sendtoclient' value="4" ></span></div>
<div>...</div>
</div>

$('#sendclientid input').click(sendclientTextArea);

  sendclientTextArea();

 function sendclientTextArea() { 

var allclientVals = [];

$('.start_booking_process_btmhref').removeClass("boldfont").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$('#sendclientval').val("");

$('#sendclientid :checked').each(function() {

var clientchecked_status = this.checked;

if (clientchecked_status == true) {

if($(this).val()=='')
{
      $('.start_booking_process_btmhref').removeClass("boldfont").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $('#sendclientval').val(""); 
}
else
{
       $('.start_booking_process_btmhref').removeAttr("disabled").addClass("boldfont");
}

}


 allclientVals.push($(this).val());

 $('#sendclientval').val(allclientVals);    

 });
```

}

you can view this on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PjP77/  please check this on ie you can see that on ff the as you click the text bx gets updated but in ie only the first textbox omehw activates the jq and not hte others.....

can anyone explain.... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I could be wrong, but I believe only classes are repeatable. **"id" attributes should be unique, and I think IE enforces that**; the reason webkit and gecko work is because they have a lenience for the sake of compatibility.

Removing all references to id tags fixes your jsfiddle problem in IE7 (it works fine in IE9).

Try adjusting your script so that instead of repeating an "id" attribute, you're repeating a class.

Good luck!

Comment: any chance you can post the jsfiddle here to see if i am doign the right thing...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Axbkk/1/   --- didnt seem to work can you see what i could have done wrong ?